# How to generate .g.dart files correctly when added POST/GET method?

Tags: flutter, retrofit, dio, json-serializable

Based on the two images here that I screenshot, I'm confused about making RestClient in Retrofit. When I deleted the Post Method, the part file (api_service.g.dart) didn't get an error. Look at this image :
[image]

But when I add Post Method, the part file (api_service.g.dart) will be error. Looks like this:
[image]

The error is:

```
error: Target of URI hasn't been generated: 'api_service.g.dart'. (uri_has_not_been_generated at [apps] lib\data\remote\api_service.dart:6)
```

and

```
error: The name '_RestClient' isn't a type and can't be used in a redirected constructor. (redirect_to_non_class at [apps] lib\data\remote\api_service.dart:11)
```

So, how is the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: what the error said?

Comment: provide the code, not screenshots of the code as well as the error.

Comment: Thanks @JohnJoe, I've edited my question

Comment: also thanks @Maz341, I've edited my question

Comment: did you try `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`?

Comment: @Hamed yes I tried but it didn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it solved by upgrading all version like retrofit, retrofit_generator and build_runner. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

```
  @GET("player_api.php?")
  Future<List<dynamic>> getbyAction(@Query("username") String username,
      @Query("password") String password, @Query("action") String action);
```

change `Future<List<dynamic>>` to `Future<dynamic>` than try to run

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Note: Also check versions of retrofit, build_runner, and retrofit_generator;

Answer (score 1):

Check the build_runner log. If the file is not generated there may be an error in your code that prevents the generator to run successfully.

Comment: I've got this error while generating :[SEVERE] retrofit_generator:retrofit on lib/data/remote/api_service.dart:
Error running RetrofitGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'InterfaceTypeImpl' has no instance method 'getDisplayString'.
Receiver: Instance of 'InterfaceTypeImpl'
Tried calling: getDisplayString(withNullability: false)

Comment: It's infuriating that there's no error reported when running `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`, but removing the problematic code and re-running this command works!